# Display ordered items within exp:store:orders oder exp:store:payment

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to retrieve the list of products in the orders or payment template tag, e.g. like in the checkout tag `{items}`?

After successful payment we display a summery page using the `{exp:store:orders}` or `{exp:store:payment}`, along with the orders summery we would like to display a list of the items related to that order (like in the control-panel).

We tried something like:

```
{exp:store:payment order_hash={last_segment}
    Your order ID: {order_id}
    ...
    {items}
        {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {title}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/items}
{/exp:store}
```

But unlike within the `{exp:channel:checkout}` tag this does not work.

Do we need to use a manual query?

Thank you, 
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The `{items}` tag does work with the `{exp:store:orders}` and `{exp:store:payment}` tags, but a little different than in the `{exp:store:checkout}` tag. Simply do not use a nested `{exp:channel:entries}` tags.

So this works:

```
{exp:store:payment order_hash={last_segment}
    Your order ID: {order_id}
    ...
    {items}
        {title}
    {/items}
{/exp:store:payment}
```

All variabes are available like in the checkout tag, e.g. `{item_qty}`,`{item_total}` etc.

Comment: You only need to use a nested `{exp:channel:entries}` tag when you are trying to get custom fields data into your cart, checkout, payment or orders data. For example if you wanted to show an image thumb from a custom field you would need to nest the channel entries tag in the orders tag.

Comment: You would probably be better off using the `{exp:store:orders}` tag over the payment tag if you are displaying the orders summary, but either way the closing tag should be either `{/exp:store:orders}` or `{/exp:store:payments}` not `{exp:store}` as in your template.

Comment: true, was a typo, added "payment" so that the closing tag matches the opening tag.

Comment: `{exp:store:payment order_hash={last_segment}` should also be `{exp:store:payment order_hash="{last_segment}"}`